# Adding onclick event in custom menus

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have created menu from admin panel, now I have to add onclick event in li tag of each menu item like below:

```
<li><a href="#m-track-suite" onclick="hide('drop')">Track Suits</a></li>
```

For this I have installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/jin-menu/ plugin follow the steps as described in this documentation but onclick event not appearing.Below is the screen shot :

[image]

Comment: Every menu item comes up with his unique ID. You can use it for firing click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Add this code a file which loads on each page or your header.php in themes

```
jQuery('a[href="#m-track-suite"]').click(function(){

//...do something..;

});
```

Comment: Thanku for your reply, but I have 10 to 12 menu items with different ids, I think for each one separate piece of code is not appropriate